# Program my application to show message box when opened on by shortcut

Tags: vb.net, scheduled-tasks, messagebox

I have an application that is generally run on a scheduled task. However I also have a shortcut on the desktop to run the application there and then. I am wanting a message box to pop up when the user double clicks on to the shortcut, but NOT on the scheduled task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a command line argument to the shortcut and then check for the argument when your application starts, if found you are running from the desktop.

Comment: I was thinking this but I've already got multiple command line arguments in my application and didn't want to use too many in case someone else has to alter my code at a later date. I suppose if I add useful comments it shouldn't be too bad